# Could language coexist with complex natural signals?

Tags: creature-design, fantasy-races, language

The species in question would have a humanoid level of intelligence and inventiveness

Their abilities of language would be less developed than humans, but would still work well enough for a society

They would also have a set of natural signals (like laughter or facial expressions in humans) which are similar to that of social animals without language, though perhaps slightly simpler. They would generally be able to get through an average day without using language

Could such a species realistically exist? Or would they need to be specialized for a particular method?

Comment: “They would also have a set of natural signals (like laughter or facial expressions in humans)” it appears you already have an answer.

Comment: @Topcode Human natural signs aren't all that complex

Comment: *Humans* use many complex sets of non-linguistic signs in addition to language. Humans realistically exist. Examples of such sets of non-linguistic signs: hand signs, as used in the military or by traffic directing police persons; traffic signs (not the wordy American signs, the worldless signs used everywhere else); the not-so-subtle eye contact and smiling used when flirting; choice of clothing for different occasions; gestures indicating respect, or obedience, or assent etc.

Comment: *"Human natural signs aren't all that complex":* And yet, traffic agents or sports referees actually make do without speaking.

Comment: Ants have a "society" - social hierarchy, specific roles, communication vertically and horizontally in their groups. So do Hyenas. What do you mean by a society?

Comment: @AlexP None of those examples are natural signals

Comment: They are certainly not supernatural. (And, in general, mammals have very few if any complex instincts. Almost all complex behaviors in mammals are learned. Not even opening your eyes wide and smiling to a prospective amorous interest is instinctual. That's just how us mammals are made.)

Comment: I've not read it for several years, but a good primer on instinctive human behaviours/body-language, and how they manifest in different cultures is Manwatching: A Field Guide to Human Behaviour, by Desmond Morris. It shows us the remarkable complexity and variety of such things, worth getting your hands on a cheap second-hand copy.

Comment: @IchthysKing since you don't agree with the comments, can you describe in greater detail what you are looking for, and how does what you are looking for differen from early humans?

Comment: It's hard to get what you want. Without needing to include more subtle things like body language, Humans have entire languages that don't rely on a single word, from ones based solely on whistles to others that use only hand gestures (which are 100% functional, but not as practical, as they require you to be able to see who you're communicating with). That coupled with the fact that we do have spoken languages simultaneously makes it hard to see what you're having trouble with. Do you mean whether they'd prioritize one type of communication over the other like we do? Or something else?

Comment: Could you define what natural signals are? People here talk about body language, but in humans, it is not 'natural', it is a learnt behaviour and people in different cultures use different body languages. The same goes for laughter and facial expressions. There is a lot of research on smiling and its cultural meaning and usage, you might be interested in looking it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Of course, spoken language will coexist with body language**

At first glance, the answer to the title question is clearly "Yes". Language could take over everything, body language could do most work, but with Human language, it's always the combination. They keep frowning in disapproval, or nodding their heads, before explaining their objections in language. Language and body language are complementary. They will coexist, supporting each other.

**Two different realms**

Social animals are able to *communicate.*

Using language is another ball game, a different realm. *Sign language* is a form of body expression that can form language constructs. All other language is spoken language.

The difference: language has no fixed expressions for every separate thing, it provides an *agreed* grammar to express things, it has *agreed* lexical components. The speaker can compose a statement, or devise a new statement. Body language can change too, but it will not be recognized at first and it  takes culture time to accept it. Language is really flexible, a listener can grab a sentence never previously heard.

**A living language needs to be used !**

Your silent creatures could develop and maintain some language, but a language needs to be spoken, to develop. Your species won't develop spoken language properly, when they tend to avoid it, or  don't require it. A language needs to be fed, to stay alive and develop: it is a multi-purpose (or *meta*) means of communications that needs to be filled in.  If you don't have anything to fill it with.. it will become a dead language.